# Filtering by taking out one column Pandas/Python/DataFrames

Tags: python, filter, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe with 200 columns and I want to take out just one column. I've read several articles/questions about filtering out select columns. However, I don't want to call out

```
 data=data.loc[:,['All 199 Columns Except for the One I don't want']
```

Nor does this work

```
 data=data[data.columns.values != 'Shared Cart']
```

Another option I tried with no success...

```
 data=data-data['Shared Cart']

 List = 'Shared Cart'
 data=data[-data.columns.isin(List)]
```

Not sure what else I can do to filter out the one column I don't want in my dataframe.

Any advice?

Answer (score 0):

Remove the offending column:

```
del data['Shared Cart']
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `drop` to retain your original data. If this is not feasible because of memory constraints, you should prefer unutbu's answer.

```
modelling_data = data.drop ('Shared Car', axis=1)
```